# Wheren can I find the source code of the pre-implemented NodeJs packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

Ist there a possibility to view the source code of NodeJS packages like `fs` or `crypto`??

Are they implemented in Javascript or is their implementation part of the C++ kernel of NodeJS?

I tried to look for `getRandomBytes` on GitHub at https://github.com/nodejs/node (it's a function that's part of the crypto-module), but there are no search results.

Comment: The method is [`randomBytes`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) not `getRandomBytes`

Comment: See [this search](https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?utf8=✓&q=randomBytes&type=)

Comment: perhaps `getRandomBytes` is part of a library you've installed

Comment: And the internal modules are in the lib directory

Comment: Thanks. It looks like someone gave me the wrong function name (getRandomBytes instead of randomBytes).